# Volterra operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let‎ ‎$ f \in L‎^{2} [‎ 0 ,‎ 1‎ ‎]‎ $‎.

‎**define:‎**
$ V( f ( t ) ) = ‎\int‎_{0}‎^{t} f‎ (‎ ‎s) ‎ds‎ $.(Volterra operator)

‎we ‎know ‎that‎ ‎$ ‎ V( f ( t ) ) ‎\in C‎ [‎ 0‎ ,‎ 1‎ ‎] ‎‎$ ‎for ‎all ‎‎$ f \in L‎^{2} [‎ 0‎ ,‎ 1‎ ‎]‎‎‎‎ $
‎

> **can ‎we ‎find‎ ‎‎$ ‎\sigma (‎ V‎ )‎ =‎ ‎\{ 0‎ ‎\}‎ $ ‎and ‎$ r ( V ) = 0 $‎‎‎?‎‎**

‎‎
‎
we ‎have‎ ‎$ V‎^{*} :‎ ‎L‎^{2} [‎ 0‎ ,‎ 1‎ ]‎ ‎‎‎\longrightarrow L‎‎^{2} [‎ 0‎ ,‎ 1‎ ‎]‎ $,

‎so‎ ‎$ < f , V f > = < V‎^{*} f‎ ,‎ f‎ ‎>‎ $‎
‎

and‎ ‎$ V‎^{*} (‎ f‎ (‎ t‎ ‎)) =‎ ‎‎\int‎_{‎t‎}‎^{‎1‎} f‎ (‎ ‎s) ‎ds‎ $‎‎

> **is ‎it ‎right ‎to ‎say‎ ‎$ V‎^{*} V‎ $‎ ‎is ‎compact ‎and ‎normal ‎?‎**
>   ‎

Comment: Could you remind what you mean by normal? I forgot the definition

Comment: The  compactness is ok since both operator are compact

Comment: I believe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808176/how-to-show-that-the-volterra-operator-is-not-normal) shows that it is not normal.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the resolvent $(V-\lambda I)^{-1}$ by solving for $g$, given $f$. This is a first order ODE that can be solved with an integrating factor. Assuming $\lambda \ne 0$,
$$
                  Vg -\lambda g = f \\
                  Vg -\lambda \frac{d}{dx}Vg = f
$$
The solution $g=R(\lambda)f$ is defined for all $\lambda\ne 0$ by
$$         R(\lambda)f = -\frac{1}{\lambda}f-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)/\lambda}f(t)dt.
$$
This operator is easily shown to be bounded on $L^2$. So $\sigma(V)=\{0\}$ because the spectrum is contained in $\{0\}$ and cannot be non-empty because $V$ is a bounded operator. $V$ cannot be normal because the norm and spectral radius are the same for a normal operator, and the spectral radius of $V$ is $0$ because $\sigma(V)=\{0\}$.

$V$ is compact. So $V^*V$ is compact. And $V^*V$ is selfadjoint and, hence, normal.

Comment: There is some kind way to know the spectrum of $Tf(x)=\int_{0}^{x}yf(y)dy+x\int_{x}^{1}f(y)dy$? I know that is compact, so all the spectrum is eigenvalues and {0}. I wrote $Tf=\lambda f$ and I've found $\lambda f''=-f+2f(1)$. I solved, but is not so trivial to find yet. Some types? I thought that there is some analogus way to do

Comment: @LuizaSilva : The spectrum is the set of singularities of the resolvent operator as a function of $\lambda$. Can you see the singularities of $R(\lambda)$ as a function of $\lambda$?

Comment: I tried to see $(\lambda I- T)f=0$, but I couldn't arrive in a good solution. Now, I just realize that T is a normal operator, can I say something about this operator?

Comment: @LuizaSilva I have derived for you the explicit formula for the resolvent. It's called $R(\lambda)$ and it is defined and bounded for all nonzero $\lambda$. So the spectrum is $\{ 0\}$

Comment: @LuizaSilva There is no mention of your T in the original problem. Where did it come from?

Comment: I'm trying to find the eigenvalue of this operator $T$ and I thought that is analogous to your idea, but isn't

Comment: @LuizaSilva : If you want to ask about a different question, then you should post the new question. No harm in doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140316/discussion-between-disintegrating-by-parts-and-luiza-silva).